# how to use dojo.setStyle for setting the color

Tags: dojo

I am having two questions with respect to this above program

1. The Width of the button is appearing very small
2. How can I change the color of the button programatically means onclick of this button I have a function?

   dojo.setStyle("bid" ,"color" ,"red");

But both aren't working

```
<html>
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"/>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js"
djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
 </script>
    <script>
         dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="claro">
<div  dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="bid" style="color: green;width: 335px; font-size:12px;"></div>Save

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you want is style, not setStyle, so use:

```
dojo.style("bid", "color", "red");
```

To make the button bigger, put some text in the div:

```
<div  dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="bid" style="color: green;width: 335px; font-size:12px;">Save</div>
```